# C#: Form templating system

Tags: c#, winforms, template-engine

I want to create a form templating system in a c# winforms application. Admins could create and manage forms whereas users could fill them out (Like in Lotus Notes or Access). This needs to be in a user control. I've been playing with solutions such as XSL and possibly dynamically creating HTML, but these seem pretty ghetto. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you google for "hosting windows forms designer" you'll find examples of how you can embed the windows forms designer in your own application (as a user control).